# Fastest way to make a list-like object containing integers in python

Tags: python, list

#### What is the fastest way to make a list-like object containing integers/floats (very simple datatypes) in python?

### What do I mean by "list-like"?

This means I want to have an object that supports the two (very) basic operations of a list: getting an object in a certain index (1) and changing its value (2).

### What posts did I come across before posting this and why didn't they solve my problem?

I came across these two: [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521674/initializing-a-list-to-a-known-number-of-elements-in-python) [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712002/create-an-empty-list-in-python-with-certain-size)

They didn't solve my problem because all the solutions to them were simply too slow: in my PC `array.array('i',(0,)*10 ** 8)` resulted in an error (lol); `[0 for _ in range(10**8)]` took about 15 seconds (wow!); `[0] * 10 ** 8` took 2.3 seconds; `[None] * 10 ** 8` took 1.8 seconds; (1.8sec could be faster...)

## What did I try to do?

I tried using the `ctypes` module

```
from ctypes import c_int
array = (c_int * 10 ** 8)()
```

The code above took only 0.7 seconds ... but is there a way to make it faster? Besides being fast it has some disadvantages:

1. As it uses the c/c++ variables' skeleton, the integers in it will be in a "not as unlimited as python" integer value range
2. You can't have more than one datatype in the list
3. You have to import a module to use it

Is it really possible to do what I'm asking? Is there a faster way rather than using the `ctypes` module? If so make sure that you are using a 'built-in' / 'pre-installed' module.

#### Edit:

### Why can't I simply install some module, like numpy?

I'm using python for competitive programming and most interpreters/judges just won't allow external libraries.

### Can we have custom objects stored with array.array?

I can see many of the answers use the `array` function of the `array` module. They all use 'i' to specify we want to store integers. Is it possible to make a class and create an `array.array' containing it? For example:

```
class Point:
 def __init__(self, x, y):
  self.x = x
  self.y = y

# make array.array object with all indexes containing a Point with atributes x and y with value 0
# an example with a list of what I want to do is this:
# l = [Point(0, 0) for _ in range(10**3)]
```

Comment: Have you considered `numpy`? If you're talking about performance in large numeric computations, you should not be worried about importing modules. See [Why NumPy instead of Python lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993984/why-numpy-instead-of-python-lists)

Comment: you've got `bytearray(10**8)` too. Values are limited in range (0-255) but it's pretty fast

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `array.array('i',(0,) * 10**8)` resulted in an error (lol)

You didn't specify what error you got - that works for me, although it's not very fast because it builds an intermediate tuple and immediately discards it. Using Python's built-in types, `array.array` will probably result in best performance, provided you avoid the tuple:

```
a = array.array('i', (0,)) * 10**8
```

> The code above took only 0.7 seconds ... but is there a way to make it faster?

It will be hard to beat `array.array` if you're not allowed to create or import C extensions. On my several years old machine the above takes 0.6 seconds. You can further optimize it by increasing the size of the initial array. For example, this produces the same result, but is almost 3x faster (!):

```
# 0.22 s
a = array.array('i', (0,) * 10) * 10**7
```

On my machine the following version works best:

```
# 0.19 s
a = array.array('i', (0,) * 100) * 10**6
```

Further increasing the initial array size doesn't help and soon starts degrading performance.

To get better efficiency, consider alternative approaches, such as a lazy list or an altogether different data structure tailored for your use case. Given the context of a competition, that might be what is actually being sought.

Be aware, however, that each solution will have different tradeoffs. For example, a lazy array such as one provided by @KonstantinNikitin will be extremely efficient to construct, but its `__getitem__` and `__setitem__`, implemented in pure Python, will be several orders of magnitude slower than those of list or `array.array`. Which is better for you boils down to what operations are more frequent in your program, and that is up to you to find out.

Comment: I didn't specify the eror because when I ran it on my machine it crashed and I had to restart it lol ... but your solution is the best one so far!

Comment: I really like the idea of your `array.array`! Also may be useful to do some wrapping above the bytearray, where you read, for example, to access item `i` values from [4 * i .. 4 * i + 4).

    >>> timeit.timeit('x = bytearray(10 ** 8)', '', number=1)
    0.0671752679918427
    >>> timeit.timeit('x = array.array("i", (0,) * 100) * 10 ** 6', 'import array', number=1)
    0.30561141700309236

Comment: @ArthurQ Ouch. While a 100 million element tuple is rather large by Python standards, it's not huge enough that it should be causing a crash, especially as it only contains references to the same `0` object.

Comment: @KonstantinNikitin `array.array` is probably the most underrated Python standard library module, and was so even before it was made somewhat obsolete by `numpy`. Interestingly, in PyPy `array.array('i', (0,)) * 10**8` is instantaneous because PyPy recognizes and special-cases construction of an array consisting of all zeros.

Comment: By the way ... can you also use this module to make an array of custom objects? For example: making an array of points (consider you coded the 'Point' class yourself and it has the 'x' and 'y' attributes)

Comment: @ArthurQ Not directly, but you could create two arrays, one for all x's and one for all y's. If done right, this could be encapsulated in a `PointArray` class that hides the gory details. But please ask a separate question about details of that, because adding this new requirement renders all existing answers obsolete.

Comment: @user4815162342 yeah but what if I need to sort them based on the distance from the origin (example) using only the 'sort' function (keeping x and y coords)?

Comment: @ArthurQ You can sort them by sorting a list of indices and then rearranging both arrays. I'm not sure if performance will be acceptable, but sorting a list of `Point`s would not be much faster either. Again, this sounds like good material for a new question.

Comment: @KonstantinNikitin The trouble with wrapping the `bytearray` is that then you pay the price of `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` implemented in Python, in which case you might as well use your `LazyArray` and have instantaneous construction.

Answer (score 3):

I would just use the `numpy` module, which supports fast array operations.

For example making an array with numbers 0 to 10**8:

```
import numpy as np
import time

b = time.time()
a = np.linspace(0, 10**8, 10**8)
c = time.time()
print(c-b)
>>>0.5000154972076416
```

Or making an array of 0s that is 10**8 long:

```
b = time.time()
a = np.zeros(shape=(10**8,))
c = time.time()
print(c-b)
>>>0.0
```

The main reason why numpy is this fast is because it is implemented in C.

EDIT:
If you want to do it with only pre-installed packages, you can try using the `array` package:

```
import array
import time
r = time.time()
a = array.array('i', [0]) * (10**8)
print(time.time()-r)
>>>0.15627217292785645
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd say that you can try different approaches:

1) `numpy`. It's really a standard for arrays. It comes with a cost of crossing Python <-> C boundary for each operation, but it really depends on  your task.

```
x = numpy.array(10 ** 8)

timeit.timeit('x = numpy.array(10 ** 8)', 'import numpy', number=1)
4.195800283923745e-05
```

2) lazy initialization (like JavaScript arrays).

```
class LazyArray:
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.storage = {}
        self.size = size

    def check(self, i):
        if i < 0 or i >= self.size:
            raise RuntimeError() 

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        self.check(i)
        return self.storage.get(i, 0)

    def __setitem__(self, i, value):
        self.check(i)
        self.storage[i] = value

x = LazyArray(10 ** 8)
x[10]
>> 0
x[10] = 5
x[10]
>> 0
```

Comment: Using dictionaries can be slow ... insertion and getting index operations may take O(1) but they can also take O(n) (worst case)

Comment: Yeah, lazy initialisation has it's own price. You can try to mix then. Like manually splitting the interval to list of [0 .. sqrt(size)] dicts.

Answer (score 2):

If you *really* only want these two properties:

> getting an object in a certain index (1) and changing its value (2)

then you can just use a `collections.defaultdict`:

```
import collections
my_list = collections.defaultdict(lambda: 0)
```

which is rather fast (~0.4 μs):

```
$ python3 -m timeit -s 'import collections' 'collections.defaultdict(lambda: 0)' 
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.417 usec per loop
```

however, actually using it will probably be quite a bit slower than any of the types suggested in other answers.

Comment: I like this out-of-the-box approach.

Comment: `defaultdict(int)` is a more efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

For cases where you only need integers from 0 to 255, `bytearray` objects are quite fast to create:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('bytearray(100000)', number=1000)
0.005567271093696036
>>> timeit.timeit('array.array("B", [0])*100000', 'import array', number=1000)
0.36631167401839093
>>> timeit.timeit('array.array("i", [0])*100000', 'import array', number=1000)
0.56494557472422
```

Unlike `array.array`, this zeros the allocation directly instead of copying from an object initialized with zeros.