# When I create 2 arrays of the same contents but different techniques, one acts strange with rows manipulaton

Tags: python

When I create these 2 arrays with different techniques but effectively the same idea, the first one reacts way differently when I attempt to edit a SINGLE row and not the entire thing. When debugging, I see it editing every column at once rather than a single row column at once. [I was following this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521674/initializing-a-list-to-a-known-number-of-elements-in-python). The code I am comparing is as follows:

```
arr=[[0]*8]*8
for i in range(len(arr[0])):
    arr[0][i]=1
print(arr)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

```
arr=[[0 for j in range(8)] for i in range(8)]
for i in range(len(arr[0])):
    arr[0][i]=1
print(arr)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: copies vs new objects

Comment: Oh haha that's so silly, thank you!